# Stop vim indenting new lines after comma in plain text files

Tags: vim, gvim

I use vim/gvim as my default text editor.

When I'm editing plain text files with no syntax highlighting, it automatically adds indentation when I press enter, if the last character on the finished line is a comma.

This indentation is variable length, to bring the cursor under the first word in the previous line.

e.g. the key sequence

```
a <space> b <enter> a <space> b , <enter> a <space> b
```

produces this

```
a b
a b,
  a b
```

If I `:setlocal filetype?` I get `filetype=text`.

Here is my `~/.vimrc`:

```
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" Use Vim settings, rather then Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

if has("vms")
  set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup        " keep a backup file
  set backupdir=/home/bernie/.vim/tmp
  set directory=/home/bernie/.vim/tmp
endif
set history=500     " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
set incsearch       " do incremental searching


  set autoindent    " always set autoindenting on
  set smartindent   " guesses indents
  set cindent       " more flexible indenting.
    set cino =>s,   " 1 tab after each brace
    set cino+=e0,       " Braces starting on a new line treated the same
    set cino+=n0,       " Treat ifs the same even if there are no braces
    set cino+=f0,       " Functions aren't special either.
    set cino+={0,}0,^0, " No per-brace fiddling.
    set cino+=:0,=s,    " Don't indent "case"s but indent their bodies
    set cino+=l1,       " Cases with braces get no extra indentation
    set cino+=g0,h0,    " No extra indents for "public", "private", etc.
    set cino+=p0,t0,    " No extra indents for function types and locals
    set cino+=+s,       " Continued lines are indented.
    set cino+=cs,C1,N0, " Indent multi-line comments.
    set cino+=)50,*50   " Search wide for unclosed brackets and comments
                " Don't understand the (n un Un wn mn commads
  set guioptions-=T " no toolbar
  set vb t_vb=      " flashing
  set columns=80
  set lines=80
  colorscheme koehler

  set autowrite         " save all buffers before certain commands

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" This is an alternative that also works in block mode, but the deleted
" text is lost and it only works for putting the current register.
"vnoremap p "_dp

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

endif " has("autocmd")

set guifont=Monospace\ 8

set formatoptions-=t
```

I don't want vim to try to be clever with plain text files. How do I turn this off, but leave auto/smart indentation on for other file types?

Comment: This has nothing to do with auto- or smartindent. We'd need your `.vimrc` do reproduce this. Is any filetype detected for those plain text files, or is `:setlocal filetype?` empty?

Comment: @IngoKarkat I have updated the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is caused by the enabled `'cindent'` option. I tried fiddling with the `'cino'` options, but apparently it is not affected by that (but I have little experience with those).

I think you should disable c-indenting for plain text files, and just go with smart- and autoindent.

As you have a filetype detection (to `text`) for those files, just add the following:

Put the corresponding `setlocal nocindent` command into `~/.vim/ftplugin/text.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType text setlocal nocindent` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.